R openxlsx - how to create overflowing array formula?
I am trying to create an overflowing array in R using openxlsx. My end result will have the user change items into row 1, so I need the UNIQUE formula to dynamically add/remove values after exporting.
Here's my reprex:
library(openxlsx)

testwb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(testwb, "Sheet1")

df <- data.frame(c("one"),
                 c("two"),
                 c("three"),
                 c("two"),
                 c("four"))

writeData(testwb, sheet = "Sheet1", x = df, startCol = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = FALSE)

writeFormula(testwb, sheet = "Sheet1", x = "TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:E1, TRUE))", array = FALSE,
             startCol = 1, startRow = 3)

saveWorkbook(testwb, file = "test_output.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

openXL(testwb)

My expected output is this (works as intended with this formula):

However, the code results in errors whether I set "array" within writeFormula to both TRUE and FALSE.
Output using array = FALSE (forces @ symbols into the formula):

and output using array = TRUE (forces {} brackets):

Any ideas how I can achieve the first output? Thanks :)

You may need to update your Excel.

To clarify - the output works as intended when I enter the formula directly into Excel (or tidy the formula up after export). It's only the output from openxlsx forcing either the {} brackets or @ symbols which breaks it.

Then you may need to update your R packages because I don't get the curly brackets when I run your code.

Oh interesting. I have version 2406 of excel in Microsoft365 which appears to be the most up-to-date version, and there are no updates available for openxlsx. I also get the same error with openxlsx2.

I haven't been able to figure this out, however have done a workaround by not allowing it to overflow and accessing each value individually using INDEX(UNIQUE(...), n)

If that solved your problem, you are very welcome to answer your own question. :)

@OP, things like this are not possible with openxlsx. I have implemented a solution for openxlsx2 see here

@JanMarvin if you use openxlsx2 to load a workbook that already has spill formulas (eg filter()) in them, will they be correctly interpreted when writing back to an xlsx file?  openxlsx doesn't seem to be able to do that.

yes, it will be correctly interpreted.
